# Qt QML GridLayout Layout.columnSpan not working properly

Tags: qt, qml

Consider the following GridLayout:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts


Item {
    id: container

    anchors.fill: parent

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "grey"

        Rectangle {
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.margins: 10

            color: "transparent"

            GridLayout {
                width: parent.width
                height: 200

                columnSpacing: 5
                rowSpacing: 5

                rows: 6
                columns: 4

                Repeater {
                    model: ["line 1:", "data 1",
                        "line 2:", "data 2",
                        "line 3:", "data 3",
                        "line 4:", "data 4",
                        "line 5:", "data 5",
                        "line 6:", "data 6"
                    ]

                    delegate: Item {
                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                        Layout.fillHeight: true
                        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignTop

                        Layout.columnSpan: index % 2 == 0? 1 : 3

                        Rectangle {
                            width: parent.width
                            height: 30
                            color: "red"

                            Text {
                                anchors.fill: parent
                                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
                                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                                text: modelData
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Getting that result:

[image]

I need the right column (data) to be 3:1 to the left column (title).

Seens that the following line has some logic mistake:

```
Layout.columnSpan: index % 0 == 0 ? 1 : 3
```

How can I make left column span=1 and right column span=3?

Answer (score 0):

I removed some layers from your example for simplicity, and assigned widths to the columns rather than try to span multiple columns. Not sure if this is something you can use, but it works.

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts

Window {
    id: window
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    
    GridLayout {
        id: gridLayout
        width: parent.width
        height: 200
        
        rows: 6
        columns: 2
        
        Repeater {
            model: ["line 1:", "data 1",
                "line 2:", "data 2",
                "line 3:", "data 3",
                "line 4:", "data 4",
                "line 5:", "data 5",
                "line 6:", "data 6"
            ]
            
            delegate: Rectangle {
                width: (model.index % 2 === 0) ? window.width * 0.25 : window.width * 0.75
                height: 30
                color: "red"
                
                Text {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
                    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                    text: modelData
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hummm... works, but I expected a `colSpan` solution... Can't find out why it does not work properly...

Comment: The documentation is quite brief, but it doesn't appear that Layout.columnSpan sets widths -- you still need some combination of minimumWidth, preferredWidth and maximumWidth if you don't want the default values. It's probably better to use Layout.preferredWidth in the rectangle -- I tried it and it works fine.